# How to plot ROC for LOOCV by hand based on output probabilities returned by SVM?

Tags: svm, roc

I want to plot ROC for Leave-one-out (LOO) cross-validation (CV).
I have the decision values as well as probability values for each class from SVM classifier.
I did see the answer to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/how-do-you-generate-roc-curves-for-leave-one-out-cross-validation); however, the answer was not complete about plotting ROC according to probabilities.

As an example the output of my classifier for one sample is like this:

```
c1a
  1 
attr(,"decision.values")
          1/0
c1a 0.1338180
attr(,"probabilities")
            1         0
c1a 0.6824716 0.3175284
Levels: 0 1
```

Comment: @user777 I have 120 samples not one sample. In my post, I just have shown the output of SVM for one sample.

Comment: @user777 How? That is exactly my problem.

Comment: No, my question is how I can calculate FPR and TPR from these probabilities to plot ROC?

Comment: Answered here. The only difference is that you specify you're using LOOCV but that's irrelevant to the procedure. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand