# How to compute $R^2$ of test set in leave-one-out CV?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, goodness-of-fit

In leave-one-out cross validation, at each iteration, my test set is composed by only one data point - precisely the "left out", to be compared with the predicted one, using the estimated coefficients from the train set. Normally, for the train set, one would compute the $R^2$ over several observations and fitted values. For the test set, how should one compute the $R^2$ between a pair of numbers, namely one observed and another predicted value? Is there a common convention on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gather all your predictions for the entire set (since each prediction is generated via CV, it's unbiased), and calculate the $R^2$ on all true vs prediction.

Comment: I see, that solves. I guess I could bootstrap on this to estimate the uncertainties for this R2, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: Do you have a reference that one can compare different models like that? (i.e. for each model: perform leave one out crossvalidation, gather all predictions on left out data and the corresponding true label and compute R^2 for each model based on all y_pred and y_true)

Comment: @Ggjj11 one google search ends up here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/how-do-you-generate-roc-curves-for-leave-one-out-cross-validation 

And, there is no other way for ROC curves for example.